# display user's bookings outside "my account" page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I know this code shows orders outside "my accounts page":

```
function woocommerce_orders() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id == 0) {
         return do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]'); 
    }else{
        ob_start();
        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/my-orders.php', array(
            'current_user'  => get_user_by( 'id', $user_id),
            'order_count'   => $order_count
         ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

}
add_shortcode('woocommerce_orders', 'woocommerce_orders');
```

So I tried this:

1. created a path in my child theme - woocommerce/myaccount/my-bookings.php
2. copied the my-bookings.php file to there
3. changed the code to:

```
function woocommerce_bookings() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id == 0) {
         return do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]'); 
    }else{
        ob_start();
        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/my-bookings.php', array(
            'current_user'  => get_user_by( 'id', $user_id),
            'order_count'   => $order_count
         ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }



}
add_shortcode('woocommerce_bookings', 'woocommerce_bookings');
```

and now I get the table but it's empty and has an error:

"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/istolar0/clients/com-unity/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/woocommerce/myaccount/my-bookings.php on line 40"

I think that's because there's no "current user" and "order" in the bookings template - so I'm not sure what to put instead there.

Comment: Bookings? Are you using some booking plugin along with WooCommerce or rather some WooCommerce addon?

Comment: Yes, it's a plugin from woocommerce, called "woocommerce bookings"